# Android loadDataWithBaseURL method not loads the given URL

Tags: android, android-webview

I have tried to display web page with custom style on my activity. So I have coded as following.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView txtLon;
    private TextView txtLt;
    private TextView txtProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnFetch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFetch);
        btnFetch.setOnClickListener(this);

        txtLon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLon);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

      if(v.getId() == R.id.btnFetch){
          WebView wv =(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

          StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

          html.append("<html>");
          html.append("<head>");

          html.append("<style>body{background:red !important}</style>");
          html.append("</head>");
          html.append("<body>");
          html.append("</body></html>");

      wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://google.com",html.toString(),"text/html","UTF-8","");;
          wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
      }

    }

}
```

after I execute the app i see only red color background( applied style give it). But It could not load web page. Why is that? What is my mistake?